# Is there a way to not use getRef() in a listview position to getKey() of a current clicked user?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working **whitout** Firebase-UI or FirebaseListAdapter.

I have made my own custom adapter, now the problem comes when I need to getKey() of the position I clicked in order to get the user uid.

I have tried this but without any success

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked: " + getmList().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //Error comes here that says cannot apply UserPojo to DatabaseReference 
             mRootReference = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position);
```

where

```
mRootReference = FirbaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

and `getAdapter(Context);` is my custom adapter

```
 public DataAdapter getAdapter(Context adapterContext) {
        return new DataAdapter(adapterContext,getmList());
    }
```

Now , I need here `mRootReference = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position)` to get the position of the user in order to pass the uid of the user in an extra that i have

```
intent.putExtra("uid", mRootReference.getKey());
```

Any idea to do this **without** getRef() ?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
mRootReference = FirbaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

I'm pretty concern of this below code.

**WRONG**

```
mRootReference = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position)
```

**RIGHT**

```
int mPositon = adapter.getRef(position);
```

Then a reference to your database node.

```
StringKey = mRootReference.child(...).child(mPositon).getKey();
```

**YOUR INTENT EXTRA**

```
intent.putExtra("uid", StringKey);
```

Comment: but I cant use getRef because I'm not using FirebaseListAdapter, I'm using just a List

Comment: Ok. According to your title, you have to retrieve each nodes `id` too. then use it to query when any item is clicked. This trick works with using a `callback` functions when you are adding your data to firebase. It will help you to retrieve the id of your data and use it to update same data by adding id field in your node table

Comment: When the item is clicked, you will retrieve their node `key/i`d and use it to query in firebase database

Comment: what .child(mPositon) should return ?

Comment: Since you are using custom listAdapter, you have to retrieve your data into `arrayList`. From this array, you can query anything you want. (Pagination would help you reduce number of item per screen).  Let me look for a link for you to learn

Comment: this youtube page will help you to understand custom `ListAdapter` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgiHb8Liyt4